# Ionic push notification for IOS fails to connect fcm

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, notifications, push

I've followed the steps from this web page: https://medium.com/one-tap-software/ionic-2-push-notifications-with-fcm-2a9078b90fe7

And I've successfully created the necessary app ids and such and configured my firebase application for iOS however when I tested the push notification functionality using the test dashboard in Wordpress, it shows this error:

"Failed to connect: 0 Apple Certification error or problem with Password phrase"

Do you know how this came about or the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate only public certificate with a password for firebase and upload in the firebase.console.

The file will be .p12 file with the password phrase.

Comment: How do you do that?